# Mockito: Mocking "Blackbox" Dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

So I have been asked to read up on mocking and BDD for our development team and play around with mocks so as to improve a handful of our existing unit tests (as an experiment).

I have ultimately chosen to go with Mockito for a number of reasons (some outside the scope of my control), but namely because it supports both stubbing and mocking for instances when mocking would not be appropriate.

I have spent all day learning about Mockito, mocking (in general) and BDD. And now I am ready to dig in and start augmenting our unit tests.

So we have a class called `WebAdaptor` that has a `run()` method:

```
public class WebAdaptor {

    private Subscriber subscriber;

    public void run() {

        subscriber = new Subscriber();
        subscriber.init();
    }
}
```

**Please note:** I do not have a way to modify this code (for reasons outside the scope of this question!). Thus I do *not* have the ability to add a setter method for `Subscriber`, and thus it can be thought of as an unreachable "blackbox" inside of my `WebAdaptor`.

I want to write a unit test which incorporates a `Mockito` mock, and uses that mock to `verify` that executing `WebAdaptor::run()` causes `Subscriber::init()` to be called.

So here's what I've got so far (inside `WebAdaptorUnitTest`):

```
@Test
public void runShouldInvokeSubscriberInit() {

    // Given
    Subscriber mockSubscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);
    WebAdaptor adaptor = new WebAdaptor();

    // When
    adaptor.run();

    // Then
    verify(mockSubscriber).init();
}
```

When I run this test, the actual `Subscriber::init()` method gets executed (I can tell from the console output and seeing files being generated on my local system), *not* the `mockSubscriber`, which shouldn't do (or return) anything.

I have checked and re-checked: `init` is `public`, is neither `static` or `final`, and it returns `void`. According to the docs, Mockito should have no problem mocking this object.

So it got me thinking: do I need to explictly associate the `mockSubscriber` with the `adaptor`? If this is a case, then ordinarily, the following would normally fix it:

```
adaptor.setSubscriber(mockSubscriber);
```

But since I cannot add any such setter (please read my note above), I'm at a loss as to how I could force such an association. So, several very-closely-related questions:

- Can anyone confirm that I've set the test up correctly (using the Mockito API)?
- Is my suspicion about the missing setter correct? (Do I need to associate these objects via a setter?)
- If my above suspicion is true, and I can't modify `WebAdaptor`, are there any circumventions at my dispose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but JMockIt makes this kind of black-box mocking pretty easy. Is JMockIt an option for you?

Comment: How is Subscriber instantiated in this class? Is it possible to override the instantiating code to return an instance that you control?

Comment: run() is the only method that uses the Subscriber, so by all means it should be a local variable inside that method. Again, I can't change the code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to inject the mock into the class which you are testing. You do not need access to Subscriber. The way mockito and other mocking frameworks help is that you do not need access to objects which you are interacting with. You do however need a way to get mock objects into the class you are testing.

```
public class WebAdaptor {

    public WebAdaptor(Subscriber subscriber) { /* Added a new constructor */
       this.subscriber = subscriber;
    }

    private Subscriber subscriber;

    public void run() {
        subscriber.init();
    }
}
```

Now you can verify your interactions on the mock, rather than on the real object.

```
@Test
public void runShouldInvokeSubscriberInit() {

    // Given
    Subscriber mockSubscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);
    WebAdaptor adaptor = new WebAdaptor(mockSubscriber);  // Use the new constructor

    // When
    adaptor.run();

    // Then
    verify(mockSubscriber).init();
}
```

If adding the Subscriber to the constructor is not the correct approach, you could also consider using a factory to allow WebAdaptor to instantiate new Subscriber objects from a factory which you control. You could then mock the factory to provider mock Subscribers.

Comment: Your snippet for WebAdaptor still has the run() method creating a new Subscriber.  FYI.

Comment: David V - after hearing myself out loud (as I wrote this question), combined with your answer and the comments above, it seems like changing the `WebAdaptor` code is my only option. Thanks for your response!

Comment: In order to keep your WebAdaptor class working with the existing code, you may also want to have a no-arg constructor that calls your new constructor.  Then the existing non-test usages of the class can use the no-arg constructor.  So the new constructor would be `public WebAdaptor(){ this( new Subscriber());}`.  Also, the constructor that has the Subscriber argument should be package-private.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change the production code and still be able to mock the functionality of the Subscriber class you should have a look at PowerMock. It works fine together with Mockito and allows you to mock the creation of new objects.

```
Subscriber mockSubscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);
whenNew(Subscriber.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockSubscriber);
```

Further details are explained in the [documentation for the PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) framework.

Comment: Read [Example #3 - Mock construction of new objects](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/10/28/untestable-code-with-mockito-and-powermock/) (scroll down) for a more exhaustive example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to inject your mock into the class under test without making any modifications to the code.  This can be done using the Mockito [WhiteBox](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.html).  This is a very good feature that can be used to inject the dependencies of your Class Under Test from your tests.  Following is a simple example on how it works,

```
@Mock
Subscriber mockSubscriber;
WebAdaptor cut = new WebAdaptor();

@Before
public void setup(){
    //sets the internal state of the field in the class under test even if it is private
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    //Now the whitebox functionality injects the dependent object - mockSubscriber
    //into the object which depends on it - cut
    Whitebox.setInternalState(cut, "subscriber", mockSubscriber);
}

@Test
public void runShouldInvokeSubscriberInit() {
    cut.run();
    verify(mockSubscriber).init();
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @zharvey was this helpful? or was I mistaken?

Comment: This will not work. When cut.run() is called a new, non-mocked, Subscriber instance will be created inside the WebAdapter and will replace the mocked version. The init method on the new instance will then be called.

Answer (score 2):

You could have used PowerMock to mock the constructor call without changing the original code:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(WebAdaptor.class)
public class WebAdaptorTest {
    @Test
    public void testRunCallsSubscriberInit() {
        final Subscriber subscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);
        whenNew(Subscriber.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(subscriber);
        new WebAdaptor().run();
        verify(subscriber).init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock the Subscriber using Mockito in your current implementation.

The problem you have is that the Subscriber is constructed and then immediately accessed, Mockito has no ability to replace (or spy) the Subscriber instance after creation but before the init method is called.

```
public void run() {

    subscriber = new Subscriber();
    // Mockito would need to jump in here
    subscriber.init();
}
```

David V's answer solves this by adding the Subscriber to the constructor. An alternative that retains the hidden Subscriber construction would be to instantiate the Subscriber in a WebAdapter no-arg constructor and then use reflection to replace that instance before calling the run method.

Your WebAdapter would look like this,

```
public class WebAdaptor {

    private Subscriber subscriber;

    public WebAdaptor() { 
        subscriber = new Subscriber();
    }

    public void run() {            
        subscriber.init();
    }
}
```

And you could use [`ReflectionTestUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) from Springframework's test module to inject dependencies into that private field.

```
@Test
public void runShouldInvokeSubscriberInit() {

    // Given
    Subscriber mockSubscriber = mock(Subscriber.class);
    WebAdaptor adaptor = new WebAdaptor();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField( adaptor  "subscriber", mockSubscriber );

    // When
    adaptor.run(); // This will call mockSubscriber.init()

    // Then
    verify(mockSubscriber).init();
}
```

`ReflectionTestUtils` is really just a wrapper about Java's reflection, the same could be achieved manually (and much more verbosely) without the Spring dependency.

Mockito's `WhiteBox` (as Bala suggests) would work here in place of `ReflectionTestUtils`, it is contained within Mockito's internal package so I shy away from it, YMMV.